# How to determine whether domain is an open or a closed region or both open and closed?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am studying Multivariable Calculus in college, and I became confused when I started learning about concepts of open region and closed region.

My question is:

Is the region **Open** or **Closed** or **Both open and close** or **Neither open nor closed** if the domain contains all points except the origin?

My understanding of the open region is not containing any boundary points.

My understanding of the closed region is containing all boundary points.

My understanding of both open and closed region is containing some but not all boundary points.

For this problem, I thought that the domain has a boundary point which is the origin but it is not contained, and thus the region is closed. And thus the domain is bounded. But then I started to think the domain is unbounded because even infinity x and infinity y is contained in the domain. And everything started to get messed up in my head.

Could anyone correct me if I am misunderstanding anything here? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Are you asking wether or not $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ is open and wether or not it is closed?

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, yes I am asking if all xy-plane but origin is open or closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of open sets is correct and so is your understanding of closed sets. However  a set is open and closed iff it has no boundary points.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but in this problem, would the origin be the boundary point if all xy-plane but origin is in the domain?

Comment: The origin  is  a boundary point of $\mathbb R^{2}\setminus \{(0,0\}$. @joh_wic

Comment: I am sorry to keep asking basic questions. The textbook defines "A region in the plane is bounded if it lies inside a disk of fixed radius. A region is unbounded if it is not bounded.". In my problem, the boundary point exist (which is origin), but I believe it is not fixed inside a disk of fixed radius. So is the region unbounded although the boundary point exist? Thank you so much.

Comment: @joh_wic Certainly. Having a boundary point has nothing to do with boundedness. An ubounded set can have a boundary point.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

You can also think of a closed set as the complement of an open set and visa versa. In this way, it may be a little bit less paradoxal.